# How to add custom feature in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

I was just wondering if it is possible to add custom features in Visual Studio 2013? For example, I want to be able to format my ASPX markup in a certain way and I want to have a custom command to do it that way. How would that be possible?

Comment: You can change formatting rules in Tools -> Options. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: No. I want it to be highly customizable. Lets say I want each aspx button to be double indented and each attribute on a new line.